# How do I add Pinterest Google Tag Manager when getting error blocked app with no administrator email for API controls?

Tags: api, web-applications, google-tag-manager, pinterest

before the error window-click relaunch:

[image]

I am trying to make ads in Pinterest and I need to `'Install the Pinterest tag on Google Tag Manager - Track conversion events etc`' and when I do, it makes you log in with your gmail account and I got an error saying The app is blocked/accessing sensitive info (refer to screenshot). I tried to find where I can allow it and I can't get access to it.

I don't have administrator access (non-gmail account) to access API Controls and fix the setting. Can you please allow Pinterest to connect accounts?

Error message screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm new to this question page and not the most tech-savvy with code - I included a screenshot, just updated with a second one in there- hopefully it shows up and no crystal ball is needed! I am trying to make ads in Pinterest and I need to 'Install the Pinterest tag on Google Tag Manager - Track conversion events etc' and when I do, it makes you log in with your gmail account and I got an error saying The app is blocked/accessing sensitive info (refer to screenshot). I tried to find where I can allow it and I can't get access to it. Does that make it more clear?

Comment: Is you google email address managed by your company? Because that message usually means that the admin of your company has blocked access, and you need to ask them: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6177431?hl=en. You should however be able to log in to GTM and install the pinterest tag manually, which will not share login information with pinterest.

Comment: Eike, thanks for your answer. I went in and was able to do it manually from Pinterest. I hope I did it right. Thanks!